# "from that of" strucutre

Tags: grammar

> The first of these is the setuid bit (octal 4000). When applied to an executable file,
> it sets the effective user ID **from that of** the real user (the user actually running the
> program) to that of the program's owner.

In the above sentence, *from that of* sounds weird to me dramatically. Could you break it up?

Answer (score 0):

"That of" is a way to avoid repetition. It can be expanded to "it sets the effective user ID from **the user ID of** the real user" (i.e., from the real user's ID).

Comment: Many thanks, could you possibly add some more examples.